Upgrading to Angular 17 - TypeScript Error - Property 'subSubProperty' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
This is happening on a working code of Angular 12, now being moved to Angular 17. I have been through various stackoverflow cases, but couldn't find a solution.
PmlaCheck Interface
export interface PmlaCheck {
  _id?: string;
  cibilSfcResults: CibilSfcResults;
  mcxActionApResults: McxActionApResults;
  mcxDefaultersResults: McxDefaultersResults;
  ....
}


Some of the properties of PmlaCheck interface are of type of various Other interfaces.
e.g. CibilSfcResults Interface
export interface CibilSfcResults {
  fnCheck: CibilSfc[];
  fmCheck: CibilSfc[];
  flCheck: CibilSfc[];
  mlCheck: CibilSfc[];
  fmlCheck: CibilSfc[];
  panCheck: CibilSfc[];
  remarks: string;        /// <<< TRYING TO ACCESS THIS PROPERTY IN CODE on a pmlaCheck object
  resRemarks: string;     /// <<< TRYING TO ACCESS THIS PROPERTY IN CODE on a pmlaCheck object
}


original code:
In the below code there is an array used this.pmlaDbData. Each element(d) of this array has a property "results", which holds string value indicating the property names of PmlaCheck interface, e.g. "cibilSfcResults".
So the expression this.pmlaCheck[d.results] is supposed to point to, e.g. this.pmlaCheck.cibilSfcResults which in turn is supposed to have properties remarks and resRemarks, i.e. this.pmlaCheck.cibilSfcResults.remarks & this.pmlaCheck.cibilSfcResults.resRemarks. TypeScript is not able to infer existence of these properties.
  pmlaCheck?: PmlaCheck;   /// property declaration


    for(const d of this.pmlaDbData) {
      if(this.pmlaCheck[d.results]) {     /// << ERROR 1 on d.results
        let formCtrlName = d.ctrlName + 'ResRemarks' ;
        let ctrlVal = this.pmlaCheck[d.results]?.resRemarks || '';   /// ERROR 2 on resRemarks
        this.form.controls[formCtrlName].setValue(ctrlVal);
      }
    }


ERROR 1:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PmlaCheck'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PmlaCheck'.ts(7053)
Resolved ERROR 1 by declaring d.results as keyof, like below
if(this.pmlaCheck[d.results as keyof PmlaCheck])

ERROR 2: To be resolved
Property 'resRemarks' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SebiList[] | UnList[] | UkSanctions[] | CibilSfcResults | McxActionApResults | ... 28 more ... | [...]'.
  Property 'resRemarks' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

How do I resolve Error 2?


Since you are dealing with dynamic access of a property, typescript is unable to infer the type without knowing the exact property being access, we can use type assertion to prevent this.
But since we are accessing the type dynamically, we need to 100% certain about the type we are going to assert, else we will get runtime errors.
export class App {
  pmlaCheck?: PmlaCheck; /// property declaration
  pmlaDbData: Array<{ results: keyof PmlaCheck; ctrlName: string }> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const d of this.pmlaDbData) {
      const key = d.results as keyof PmlaCheck;
      if (this.pmlaCheck?.[key]) {
        /// << ERROR 1 on d.results
        let formCtrlName = d.ctrlName + 'ResRemarks';
        const cibilSfcResults = this.pmlaCheck[key] as CibilSfcResults; // be 100% sure that the key accessed is of type CibilSfcResults
        let ctrlVal = cibilSfcResults?.resRemarks || ''; /// ERROR 2 on resRemarks
        this.form.controls[formCtrlName].setValue(ctrlVal);
      }
    }
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export interface McxDefaultersResults {}
export interface McxActionApResults {}
export interface CibilSfc {}
export interface PmlaCheck {
  _id?: string;
  cibilSfcResults: CibilSfcResults;
  mcxActionApResults: McxActionApResults;
  mcxDefaultersResults: McxDefaultersResults;
}
export interface CibilSfcResults {
  fnCheck: CibilSfc[];
  fmCheck: CibilSfc[];
  flCheck: CibilSfc[];
  mlCheck: CibilSfc[];
  fmlCheck: CibilSfc[];
  panCheck: CibilSfc[];
  remarks: string; /// <<< TRYING TO ACCESS THIS PROPERTY IN CODE on a pmlaCheck object
  resRemarks: string; /// <<< TRYING TO ACCESS THIS PROPERTY IN CODE on a pmlaCheck object
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1 heading-1="test">
      This is a Heading 1 styled text.
    </h1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  pmlaCheck?: PmlaCheck; /// property declaration
  pmlaDbData: Array<{ results: keyof PmlaCheck, ctrlName: string }> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const d of this.pmlaDbData) {
      const key = d.results as keyof PmlaCheck;
      if (this.pmlaCheck?.[key]) {
        /// << ERROR 1 on d.results
        let formCtrlName = d.ctrlName + 'ResRemarks';
        const cibilSfcResults = this.pmlaCheck[key] as CibilSfcResults; // be 100% sure that the key accessed is of type CibilSfcResults
        let ctrlVal = cibilSfcResults?.resRemarks || ''; /// ERROR 2 on resRemarks
        this.form.controls[formCtrlName].setValue(ctrlVal);
      }
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

